# What key is this in?

Tags: theory, harmony, key, modes

I'm new in the forum. I have lots of unasked questions about music theory because I'm a self taught musician with no formal training, so I have a lot of confusion between concepts like, for example, tonality, tonal center and modes.

Let's start with something simple and what looks like a stupid question, so I can reply explaining and my probably wrong concepts..
what key is this in?

[image: https://we.tl/t-zcHu7gDCSZ]

Answer (score 1):

The music you posted is in the *key* of C, since it has no accidentals.

It is in the *mode* of G mixolydian though, because the opening alternation between G and F is said to **establish** the myxolidian mode. Notice how the C chord is never played.

If you would bounce between any two adjacent major chords (B down to A, F down to Eb, G# down to F# etc.) you would establish B, G and G# all mixolydian respectively.

The best way to understand the underlying concepts is to listen to a lot of music examples, so you can develop an ear for the differences between modal and tonal music.